# yum + how to remove unused rpm/patch on linux redhat

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm

I am using yum to install a patch update on my RedHat Linux machine,

Is it possible to use yum on different way in order to uninstall unused rpms/patches?

My goal is to remove the unnecessary rpm/patches in order to free some space in my partition

example

I find the following command to remove old rpm kernel

```
 (package-cleanup) from - yum install yum-utils

 package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1
```

Comment: If you have some old packages which isn't required by the system it gets cleaned by the yum. e.g old kernel.  `http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/delete-remove-old-kernels-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/`

Comment: sorry - but I don't get you , do you mean that every time that I use new yum install - its actually remove the old rpm?

Comment: Check the link it says that there is a limit `installonly_limit=2` which can be mentioned in the `/etc/yum.conf `

Comment: about to remove old kernel - yes I know how to do that , what I ask is how to remove old rpms that isnt used by the OS (linux)

Comment: you can use `yum clean all`

Comment: dose the yum clean all will decrease the /var usage ?

Comment: @Yael is your question 'how do i reduce space in /var' or is it 'how do I remove stuff yum no longer needs'?

Comment: You can tell yum how many kernel packages to keep, but how does yum know if you want to keep, for example, 'strace'? That's where a system admin's brain steps in and decides what to keep and what to remove.

Answer (score 1):

When you install new updates with yum, the original installed packages and binaries are updated.  It doesn't keep multiple copies of them around.  It does cache various things however.

You can use various `yum clean` options to tidy up some of `yum`'s own cache files.

For example, `yum clean packages` will remove cached packages that have been downloaded, some of the other options may be helpful but often `yum` will just rebuild the data on next execution.

`man yum` will provide you with information on the other clean options.

Comment: This will clear the cache not the old package.

Comment: about yum clean - please advice what actually this clean ? ( installed rpm? , binaries ? )

Comment: @yael - The only way to remove installed rpm's is to use the yum remove option.

Comment: @Mongrel I clearly state it removes cached packages.

Comment: Right, but this is not the answer.

Comment: @Mongrel the answer to what?  When you install 'updates' via `yum`, the original binaries are replaced, they're not copied away.  The only cruft is cached packages.  There's nothing else to clean up.

Comment: Yael is goal is to remove the unnecessary rpm/patches in order to free some space in my partition. That is what I am trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two approaches to determine which packages can be removed:

- do a minimal installation with the RedHat release in question (which you didn't mention, by the way) and only add the packages on top which are mandatorily required for what this machine is intended to do.
  Then get the listing of all packages by name (so you could easily compare to packages with slightly newer/older versions) via
  `rpm -qa --qf="%{N} \n" | sort > minimal_install`

  Then create a backup of your machine you want to "clean up" and remove all the packages which are not on the list `minimal_install` after a thorough review.
- sort your packages by size, and try to remove some of the packages on top of the list, to get most diskspace savings with least packages.
  Get the list via e.g.
  `rpm -qa --qf '%{size}       \t%{name}\n' | sort -n > packages_sorted_by_size`
- actually check what is using up most of the diskspace, can be easily checked via e.g. 
  `du -mx /|sort -rn|head -35` and if /usr is not all over the top of the list, then the rpm packages should not be your priority for cleanups.

Answer (score 0):

RPM packages does not contains incremental updates (as contrary to e.g. Solaris). So every package contains everything needed for both upgrade and clean install.

When you call

```
yum install firefox
```

And `firefox` is already installed then yum should refuse to proceed even when there is newer version available. You should call:

```
yum upgrade firefox
```

This will install new version of the package, and them remove the old package automatically. So no left over should remain on your system.

Though you can call:

```
yum install http://foo.bar/firefox-40-1.rpm
```

and if it is newer then currently installed package, then yum automatically convert it to `yum upgrade` command.

And there is one other exception – kernel.

```
yum install kernel
```

will install new kernel (when available), but will not remove the old one (so you can boot to old one, if the new one does not work). In fact it apply on few other packages too. I will quote from `man` page of `yum.conf`:

> `installonlypkgs` List of package provides that should only ever be
>   installed, never updated.  Kernels in particular fall into this cat-
>                 egory. Defaults to kernel, kernel-bigmem, kernel-enterprise, kernel-smp,  kernel-modules,  kernel-debug, 
>   kernel-unsupported,  kernel-
>                 source, kernel-devel, kernel-PAE, kernel-PAE-debug.
>
> Note that because these are provides, and not just package names, kernel-devel will also apply to kernel-debug-devel,
>   etc.
>
> `installonly_limit` Number of packages listed in `installonlypkgs` to keep installed at the same time. Setting to 0
>   disables this feature.
>                 Default is '3'. Note that this functionality used to be in the "installonlyn" plugin, where this option was altered via
>   tokeep.   Note
>                 that  as  of  version  3.2.24,  yum will now look in the yumdb for a installonly attribute on installed packages. If that
>   attribute is
>                 "keep", then they will never be removed.

So you can have up to 3 kernel packages installed concurrently. But not 4 as yum will start removing them automatically. As you stated – you can remove old kernels by `package-cleanup --oldkernels` if you really want to.

There is no need to do anything similar for normal packages as yum do that every time during `upgrade` transaction.

You can verify it by running:

```
rpm -q kernel
```

which will likely list 3 package. While

```
rpm -q httpd
```

Should list only one package. And

```
rpm -q glibc
```

will likely list 2 packages on 64bit machine – one `x86_64` and other `i686` if you have some packages which requires `multilib` (e.g. `wine`).

Comment: Regarding the the first line, that is not correct, newer Fedora/CentOS versions and also openSUSE use delta RPMs since quite some time, and those are only differential updates. See e.g. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Presto and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE#Default_use_of_Delta_RPM

Comment: That is correct, but applydeltarpm applies a binary delta to either an old rpm or to on-disk data to re-create a new rpm. This will result to normal full rpm package, which is given as the starting point for rpm transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Running the "yum update" operation will update any packages that are on the system.

Specifically that means:
Downloading new version
Checking new version's download.
Installing/Updating new version
Checking new version's installation

The old package is not installed any longer, just the new one.  Depending on what extensions you have, you likely will only have the rpm file(s) on the disk and a "yum clean all" will remove them, along with the repository metadata, which will get regenerated on next yum operation.

Also, if you are only interested in updating firefox (for example), you can issue a "yum update firefox" command, and that will restrain updates to firefox and any dependencies that are required to get the new update to firefox installed.

As for an aforementioned incremental update, those are drpms (delta packages) and are just that -- the change in package contents from your installed version and the update this should be enabled on RHEL7/Fedora for any repository that offers them.  RHEL6 needs the yum plugin "presto" to be installed to take advantage of it, again with any repos that support it.